# How to populate SQL Server database in Docker using .NET Core app?

Tags: sql-server, angular, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app and when running it via `dotnet run` command, it automatically populates the database based on its `ConnectionString` in `appSettings.json` as shown below:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,21433;Initial Catalog=DemoDb;User Id=demo;Password=******;"
},
```

As I have already an SQL Server database in my Docker container, I want to use the existing server container and populate the new database to it in Docker. When I run the app, the new database is populated, but the app is not initialized.

I use the same port number of the `ConnectionString` above but when running the app it throws *"The underlying exception message was 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:4200)'"* error. I think it is related to using the same port with the other database in this container.

At this step:

- Should I create a new container for this new database, or use the same SQL Server container for both databases?
- Can I use the same port as the previously installed database on Docker? Or should I change it with another port in the connection string?

Sorry, I am new in Docker.

Comment: SQL Server databases don't themselves use ports.  The server instance listens on a port.  If you have another database already up and running in that container and can connect to it then you should use the same connection string that you use for the other db with the exception of the Initial Catalog value.  Initial Catalog should be set to the db name you are now working with.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of Docker suggest that if the databases are unrelated then they should exist in separate containers.

If there is a need to interact between the databases then having them on the same instance within the same container is fine.

The port is for the Instance - not the individual database, but you will need to have something in your code that identifies the database you need - whether that is a `USE` statement in your T-SQL code or an explicit connection to the new database.

What scope have you defined your user at?  Is it a contained database user? If so then you MUST specify the correct database in the connection string - if it is at the instance level as a login then that doesn't matter, but it does have to be mapped to a database user in the new database for that login.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As the databases are unrelated, I could create a new instance. In order to create a Docker instance for MSSQL, I think I should follow something like on the following page: https://www.michalbialecki.com/2020/04/23/set-up-a-sql-server-in-a-docker-container/

Comment: That blog looks fine for creating a new container. Good luck